# Can't figure out how to return a file from my project directory

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, spring-mvc

[image: I am trying to return the data.json file]

I am trying to return the data.json file

I have tried doing it in the JS call like this and have tried it without the context root and putting the actual path but it doesn't work anyway that I try it.

```
 fetch(contextRoot + '/webapp/json/data.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(contextRoot);
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(plotMarkers);
}
```

I also tried to make a call to my API and return the file, but that wasn't working either.  using (contextRoot + 'map/data') as my fetch parameter. It does go to the API and goes through the method below but still returns as a 404.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public File homePage(Map model) throws IOException {

        List<ForRent> allRentals = new ArrayList();

        allRentals = forRentDao.allRentals();

        JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for (ForRent f : allRentals) {
            array.add(f.getLat());
            array.add(f.getLon());
        }

        responseDetailsJson.put("data", (Object) array);//Here you can see the data in json format

        File file = new File("/home/brennan/_repos/rent/src/main/webapp/json/data.json");

        try {

            // Writing to a file  
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

            fileWriter.write(responseDetailsJson.toJSONString());
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        return file;
```

Im following this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/google-maps-javascript-api-the-right-way/

Im getting a 404 on anything I try. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try changing: `contextRoot + '/webapp/json/data.json'`   to `contextRoot + '/json/data.json'` and see what it does. "webapp" is likely not part of the path.

Comment: @mangotank yeah that doesn't work either for some reason. Im not sure why though because when I call my css files and stuff, I call the contextRoot + "/css/style.css".